# Am I doing this Expected Value question properly?

Tags: probability, expectation

P(Success) = (1/1000)
1-P = (999/1000)

Say Mark wins +699 Dollars if Success
        else Mark wins -1 Dollars

now say he does this 200 times how much money will he have?

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{200} 699 * \frac{1}{1000} + -1 * \frac{999} {1000}$$

Is this the proper way to answer the question?

The result says he will lose 60 dollars (i.e -60)

Comment: Your answer should be $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{200}( 699 * \frac{1}{1000} + (-1) * \frac{999} {1000})$$

Comment: sorry Thats what  I meant to write

Comment: Then your answer is correct. He gains $(0.699-0.999)$ dollars per play, thus after $200$ plays he is expected to gain $200(-0.3)$ dollars

Comment: thank you, how do I mark you as the correct answer

Comment: You dont have to, you can either wait for someone to write a more complete answer or answer it yourself once sufficient time has passed, since you now know the solution

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, expected values work like this:

Let's say I want to have $50$ babies. Very excited and all, and now I want to know how many boys I will have. Intuition tells me that, since the probability is $50\%$, I will have an expected value of $25$ boys and $25$ girls (the expected number is $np$, as you may already know).

Now I want to know my net profit. Let's say I spend $\$1,000$ on each girl (*toilet paper expenses*). However, I earn about $\$5,000$ from each boy I have (make them work young). What would my net profit be?

$$E=(5000)(25)+(-1000)(25)=\$100,000$$

I multiplied the *expected value* by the *net profit* to find the expected amount.

Now to your question, let's find the expected values first. Expected value is modeled as $np$, as shown above. Hence:

$$\text{# of successes: } \frac{1}{1000} * 200=\frac{1}{5}$$
$$\text{# of failures: } 200-\frac{1}{5}=199\frac{4}{5}$$

Just multiply the number of successes or failures by the net amount you get for each, and that will give you your expected net amount:

$$\therefore E=(+699)(\frac{1}{5})+(-1)(199\frac{4}{5})=-\$60$$